# Is 1.0em the same as 100% for font sizes?

Tags: css, font-size

I am trying to debug why having `font-size: 1.0em` in jquery-ui is causing my font sizes for my page to go huge(over 16px) without me doing any actual resizing of the fonts. Well, in Firebug I saw a weird thing for an accordion.

At the base, it had `font-size: 1.0em` but later that was overriden by `font-size: 100%`. Could that cause some sort of problem with font sizing? I was always under the impression that `100%` was the same as `1.0em`

Comment: Just FYI, you can read http://www.loadaveragezero.com/vnav/labs/CSS/font-size.php about (relative) font sizes. Doug Clifton suggests setting font-size: x-small on <body> and defining every other font size using relative sizes. That way you get a consistent look in different browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

`1em` and `100%` mean the same thing (for font-size) — "The same font-size as the parent element" (which is not the same thing as the font size the user has selected unless you are talking about the HTML element).

There are bugs in Internet Explorer when `em` is used and the font size picked from the view menu is not `medium`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, em and percentage are interchangeable in terms of font size.

I can't really tell what's going wrong in your case without code, but it may have something to do with nested font sizes:

```
<div style="font-size: 150%;">
    This text is at 150% of the base.

    <div style="font-size: 100%">
        This text is the same size as the text above.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The font is never changed unless it's to `1.0em` or `100%` though.. so those two values are the same then right?

Answer (score 0):

`em` is defined in a per user per browser basis. So em is defined for accesability in the different settings of a browser or a user preference.

It means that 1em could be `16px` or `10px` according to the user preference setting in the browser.

If you want to have more control over your font-sizes, use `px` instead of `em`.

Comment: Yea, but I mean it's like at the body level the font is 12px naturally(the way I have my browser setup), but then inside of a lot of nested elements the font somehow goes to 16px, when the only font-size changes I have is `1.0em` and `100%`